# Why isn't my cookie setting in my function?

Tags: cookies

Ive got a very simple function that simply sends mail using values from the form.

Everything works, tthe values get passed through to the wp_mail and it gets sent out no issue.

But for some reason

```
setcookie('my_cookie', $usersemail, 1 * DAYS_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
```

Even if I do

```
function set_user_cookie() {
    $school = "Some Value";
    setcookie('default_school', $school, time()+3600);
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_user_cookie');
```

That doesnt seem to work, the full function is below:

```
function deliver_mail() {

        // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
        if ( isset( $_POST['cookieformSubmit'] ) ) {

            // sanitize form values
            $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cookieForm_name"] );
            $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cookieForm_email"] );
            $number = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cookieForm_number"] );
            $downloadurl = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cookie_download_url"] );

            $message = '';
            $message .= $name;
            $message .= $email;
            $message .= $number;
            $message .= $downloadurl;

            // get the blog administrator's email address
            $to = 'myemail@myemail.com';

            $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";



            // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
            if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
                echo '</div>';
                setcookie('hbp_cookie_doc_download', $email, 1 * DAYS_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );

            } else {
                echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the text 'Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.' when I submit the form so I know its getting to that point but for some reason it just doesn't set the cookie. Im not using ingonito mode and I havent got any ad blockers and I'm accepting cookies.

So im not sure what im doing wrong any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting cookies is done via HTTP headers. This means you can't set any cookies via serverside methods (PHP->WordPress) anymore after any content has been sent to the browser.

A working example of setting cookies in WordPress (in one of my plugins):

**Cookie Manager:** https://github.com/download-monitor/download-monitor/blob/e26022f9a96abf174a874873b8cd35a0db98882b/includes/class-dlm-cookie-manager.php

**Setting the actual cookie:** https://github.com/download-monitor/download-monitor/blob/e26022f9a96abf174a874873b8cd35a0db98882b/includes/class-dlm-download-handler.php#L416

The cookie is set on the hook `parse_request` which is triggered after `init` so this probably isn't the issue in your case. Make sure there is no content send to the browser prior to your `setcookie` call.

Comment: Awesome cheers, ended up making it work using javascript but this works too cheers